# "he loves to" vs. " he would love to"

Tags: present-tense

1. He loves to join the class.
2. He would love to join the class.

Which one is correct? What is the difference?

Comment: _He loves to `VP`_ is a generic infinitive, and implies that he has `VP`-ed before, _He would love to `VP`_ can be either generic or specific to a certain occasion, in which case it becomes a polite acceptance formula for an invitation to him.

Answer (score 2):

With most verbs in English, we use the present simple only for timeless or habitual actions:

> Lions hunt their prey.
>
> I walk to work [every day].

If we want to talk about a particular instance happening at the moment, we use the continuous:

> That lion is hunting.
>
> I'm walking to work today.

Verbs of perception and inner state are different, and we do use the present simple:

> I see you.
>
> He loves her.
>
> I like them.

We don't normally use the continuous for these, though we can do so to emphasise that the action is happening right now:

> I'm seeing him go into the shop; I'm waiting ... He's come out.

But verbs like 'love, like, hate' *when they are followed by an non-finite clause* (whether infinitive or gerund) are in between. Like ordinary verbs, the simple present has timeless or habitual force:

> I like swimming.
>
> I love to go and walk round the lake.
>
> I hate cleaning the floor.

These are not referring to particular occasions, but are general statements.

But unlike ordinary verbs, these do not take the continuous at all:

> *I am liking swimming/to swim

is ungrammatical in most varieties of English (though I think it is grammatical in Indian English).

So in most Englishes, when we want to say "He [love] to join the class", neither

> He loves to join the class.

nor

> He is loving to join the class.

is available. The form used instead is

> He would love to join the class.

Answer (score 0):

"He would love to join the class" would be the correctly formed sentence, because his joining remains hypothetical at the time of the statement. "He loves to" should be followed by something present continuing, i.e. something he has done, continues to do, and will keep doing, such as "drink milk with honey." His love for milk+honey abides, while his joining the class is a one-time and future event.

Comment: "He loves to" need not be a one-time activity, it can be an enduring activity: "Although he can only be an observer, he loves to join the class. His heart lifts as he walks through the door each week."